# Why does ridiculous error information appear in Classify with Method GradientBoostedTrees?

Tags: bugs, machine-learning

The data could be classified correctly by method like `LogisticRegression`, `NearestNeigbors`.

[image]

The dataset is quiet simple,   [dataset wdx](https://www.jianguoyun.com/p/DcMnmWsQl4_9BRj0_aQFIAA)

This is not the first time I encounted with this method which across many versions.

Tested on 13.3 on windows 10.

As you can see,  `ListPlot`,`SetAlphaChannel` many interesting symbols appear in the error information. This error information seems appear in the final report stage, not training stage.

Some sliced dataset is OK to train without error.

[image]

Split problem dataset into 2 is OK.
[image]

A random dataset is OK, so the problem is related with some certain data.

```
dataset=Thread[RandomReal[{-1,1},{2000,40}]->RandomInteger[40,2000]];
```

Comment: You shouldn't ask people to download and import some random mx file. It's impossible to tell if it has any malignant code inside of it, so it's a potential vector for malware. Please provide a simple reproducible example in your post.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit OK, Let me see, actually, I don't know a small dataset to reproduce this problem. Let me do more experiments.

Comment: In that case I assume there must be some corrupt examples in the dataset. You can try and find a minimal example using bisection (split the dataset in two recursively and see which half has the problem) or something like that.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I update a dataset with .wdx format which might be more safe, and I found split the dataset into two dataset to train is OK... so might not the problem of corrupt examples.

Comment: I think it's an issue with the interactive progress reporting. Adding the option `TrainingProgressReporting -> "ProgressIndicator"` fixes things on my end.

Comment: @GregHurst Thanks, this is useful.